# Condicional con repeater field. (Wordpress + Advanced custom fields)

Tags: wordpress

Buenas tardes, a ver si me podéis echar una manita.

El tema creo que es fácil pero no consigo dar con la solución puesto que soy más diseñador que programador.

Tengo en un Wordpress con "Advanced Custom Fields" un **Repeater Field** con canales de televisión de varios tipos.

Necesito mostrar solo los canales del tipo **noticias**, siendo el campo 'tipo' un select desplegable.

```
<?php if( have_rows('canales_paquete_basico') ): ?>
<?php while( have_rows('canales_paquete_basico') ): the_row();

$value = get_sub_field('tipo');
if( $value === 'noticias' );

?>

<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">

<figure class="canales-tv">
<img src="<?php the_sub_field('imagen') ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="">
<figcaption>
<strong><?php the_sub_field('nombre'); ?></strong><br/>
<span class="label label-default"><?php the_sub_field('tipo'); ?></span>
</figcaption>
</figure>

</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

¿Alguna sugerencia?
Muchas gracias por adelantado.

---

**EDICIÓN: Solución parcial**

Finalmente lo he conseguido, pero me pinta el resultado del campo tipo fuera del div.

Alguien saber porque pasa?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código actualizado.

```
<?php
if(have_rows('canales_paquete_basico', 10)):
   while(have_rows('canales_paquete_basico', 10)): the_row();
      if(get_sub_field('tipo', 10) == 'generalista'):
         the_sub_field('tipo', 10); ?>

<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">

<figure class="canales-tv">
<img src="<?php the_sub_field('imagen', 10) ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="">
<figcaption>
<strong><?php the_sub_field('nombre', 10); ?></strong><br/>
<span class="label label-default"><?php the_sub_field('tipo', 10); ?></span>
</figcaption>
</figure>

</div>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

---

**SOLUCIÓN FINAL.**
Pes nada, yo me lo guiso yo me lo como. Dejo aqui el codigo con el resultado por si a alguien le sirve.

```
<?php
if(have_rows('canales_paquete_basico', 10)):
   while(have_rows('canales_paquete_basico', 10)): the_row();
      if(get_sub_field('tipo', 10) == 'generalista'):
          ?>

<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">

<figure class="canales-tv">
<img src="<?php the_sub_field('imagen', 10) ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="">
<figcaption>
<strong><?php the_sub_field('nombre', 10); ?></strong><br/>
<span class="label label-default"><?php the_sub_field('tipo', 10); ?></span>
</figcaption>
</figure>

</div>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Me parece que al estar en el loop, debes cambiar esto: `$value = get_sub_field('tipo');` por esto: **`$value = the_sub_field('tipo');`**

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, pero no me lo resuelve. Con este código únicamente escribe todos los tipos de nuevo.